# What is the Argb of the ControlDarkDark color in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently developing a new program. In my program, users can change the form "back color" and so on.. However in the code I cannot write `color.ControlDarkDark` because that option is unavailable, so therefore I am using the `Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)` technique. However I do not know the `ControlDarkDark` argb, so can someone find it out for me. I hope you understand my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://rnddev.blogspot.com/2011/03/any-colour-you-like-as-long-as-its-net.html) listing will help?